# Using Apache POI with RegEx to extract Uppercase Words

Tags: regex, apache-poi

So I am working on a Project to extract Uppercase words out of a .doc file in Java.  I am using regex, but that is where I run into some problems.  I am not to familiar with regular expressions but this is what I was using.

```
private static final String REGEX = "[A-Z]+";

private void parseWordText(File file) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(file);
    HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);
    WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);
    if (we.getParagraphText() != null) {
        String[] dataArray = we.getParagraphText();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
            String data = dataArray[i].toString();
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
            List<String> sequences = new Vector<String>();
            while (m.find()) {
                sequences.add(data.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
                System.out.println(data.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the code above and the regex I am getting all upper case letters, not just the all upper case words.  Basically Hello is not ok but HELLO is.

Comment: Your regex looks fine.  What is the issue?

Comment: I thought so so but I am returning every single Uppercase character in the document.  Not just the Uppercase word.  For example the System.out.println above  puts out C
D
M
T
M
A
M
A
G
S
B
S
D
S
A
S
DRIVE

Comment: So I am getting the Uppercase Words but I am also getting every single uppercase Letter.  Do I need to add a regex for not getting the uppercase letters.

Comment: Oh, just do ``[A-Z][A-Z]+``, or ``[A-Z]{2,}`` if the regex engine supports it. That'll ensure you only capture sequences of at least two capital letters.

Comment: Cool I'll try them.  I appreciate the quick response man.  Awesome!

Comment: It worked, I never snapped about the second [A-Z] the small stuff will kill ya.  Thanks acheong87.

Comment: Sure thing; happens to the best of us; glad to help!

Comment: By the way, I have a few other RegEx's I need help with later.  Should I add questions here or elsewhere?

Comment: Do search Stack Overflow (not just Google) for solutions first, but don't hesitate to ask more questions, whether new or in the comments here.  New questions will likely receive more attention.

Comment: Can we get a formal answer for this question please?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match word boundaries, use `\<` and `\>` (and remember that `\`'s need to be doubled to get them into strings, so you should write `\\<`). for the start and end of a word respectively (where a "word" is defined as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`, I think). So your regex would be `\<[A-Z]+\>`. Note that this does match one-letter words (such as the `I`, but not the `H`, in `Here I am`) as well. If you don't want those, use `{2,}` instead of `+`.